# Probability , mutually exclusive events

Tags: probability

For equally likely mutually exclusive events $A,B,C$ probability $P(A\cup B \cup C)=1$ It follows that:

a)$P(A)=0.25$

b)$P(A)P(B)P(C)<0.25$

c)$A,B,C$ are independent

d)$P(A\cup B)= \frac{3}{2}$

I don't know how to do tasks of this type, I only guess that answer $C$ is correct, but I'm not sure

Comment: Mark, what are your thoughts? What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: A, B, C are mutually exclusive $\rightarrow P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=1$ and the probability of any intersection = 0.

Now use what you know about each probability to start ruling out choices. Also, are any of the answers clearly wrong by contradiction or incoherence?

Answer (score 0):

a) We can't just say $P(A) = 0.25$ there's not enough information.

b) If you give random 3 numbers for example, $A=0.50 B=0.24 C=0.26$ it makes more than $0.25$

d) How can a $P(X)$ more than $1$ ?

So the correct answer is C.